# How to filter Optional.empty in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to filter the values with 0 to print message invalid but I get Optional.empty as result

```
 Long l = 0L;
 Optional<String> l2 = Optional.of(l).filter(t -> t>0).map(t ->t.toString());
 Optional<String>l3 =l2.filter(String::isEmpty).map(t ->"invalid");
 System.out.println(l3);
```

Need return type to be `Optional<String>`

Expected output - `Invalid`
Actual Output - `Optional.empty`

**Updated**

Need return type to be `String`

Expected output - `Invalid value 0`
Actual Output - `Optional.empty`

Comment: Seems like there is no element that is empty("")

Comment: Sorry but what you are doing looks like misuse of Optional. If you know that some value *exists* (regardless if it is correct or not, as long as it is not `null`) then Optional isn't right tool. Such cases should are better suited to be handled by simple `if(validate(value)){..handle correct value..} else {..handle incorrect value..}`. For now your question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: What if your input is not empty what is the expected result?

Comment: @YCF_L the original value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use Optional or filter, all you need is just :

```
String l3 = l > 0 ? l.toString() : "Invalid";
```

If you want to handle the null then :

```
String l3 = (l != null && l > 0) ? l.toString() : "Invalid";
```

If you want to show the number in the Invalid case, then :

```
String l3 = (l != null && l > 0) ? l.toString() : String.format("Invalid %d", l);
```

Comment: did not get u , u mean to use it inside filter , `String l3 = l > 0 ? l.toString() : "Invalid";`

Comment: @coder25 no, you don't need to use Optional no filter just like it is.

Comment: In my actual use case l2 is Optional

Comment: @coder25 but *why* is it there in the first place? Why involve Optional if your goal (based on how your question looks like now, not sure if it is your *real* goal) can be achieved in simpler way shown in above answer?

Comment: @coder25 why you want to use Optional? can you explain what you want to do exactly with your code?

Comment: because my pojo has Optional while retrieving values in actual scenerio

Comment: @coder25 please show us the original problem, don't post an XY problem

Comment: @coder25 Sorry but I don't follow. It is like saying "it is there because it is there" which doesn't give us much. Usually things are in some place because someone made decision that it should be there, and I am asking for reasons behind that decision (why someone - author of code, which is probably you - though that Optional must be used in that place?).

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Java 9+, you can use `or`, which takes an *alternative* `Optional` if the present one is empty:

```
Optional<String> l3 = l2.filter(String::isEmpty)
                       .or(() -> Optional.of("invalid"));
```

Comment: thanks. In case I do not need Optional need to print `Invalid value +l2` , orElse wont work.Any idea how we can achieve

Answer (score 1):

How about not using filter.

```
String l3 = l2
    .map(Object::toString)
    .orElse("invalid");
```